# Is this Chromium devtools z-index popup giving wrong/outdated advice?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, css-grid, chromium, z-index

I have a grid setup where I have several `div` elements that overlap each other.  As I want to control which order they overlap in, I set the CSS `z-index` on some of them.  When I then examine these elements in Chromium dev tools, I get the following:

[image: devtools screenie]

Is this advice not incorrect, probably because it was written before CSS grid was finalized?  When an element in a grid is `static`, it seems like `z-index` most certainly does have the effect of controlling rendering order in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the element is a grid item (it's not clear from your image that that's the case), then yes, that advice is incorrect. [The specification for z-axis ordering of grid items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#z-order) says:

> ... painting order of grid items is exactly the same as inline blocks [CSS2], except that order-modified document order is used in place of raw document order, and **z-index values other than auto create a stacking context even if position is static** (behaving exactly as if position were relative). Thus the z-index property can easily be used to control the z-axis order of grid items.

*Why* it is incorrect can only be speculated at. I wouldn't like to say whether the advice is out-of-date or just mistaken.

Flex items are treated similarly, although Chrome does not offer the same incorrect advice for them.